# How do I get the current state of a thread (e.g. blocking, suspended, running, etc..) in win32?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, internals, thread-state

I couldn't find a documented API that yields this information.

A friend suggested I use NtQuerySystemInformation. After looking it up, the information is there (see [SYSTEM_THREAD](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/System%20Information/Structures/SYSTEM_THREAD.html) ) but it is undocumented, and not very elegant - I get the information for all threads in the system.

Do you know of a more elegant, preferably documented API to do this?

Comment: I posted a working class here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949725/how-to-get-thread-state-e-g-suspended-memory-cpu-usage-start-time-priori

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than using `NtQuerySystemInformation`.
However it could be less complicated, that's true, but Microsoft lacks an implementation.

I posted a working class here that is very elegant to use:

[How to get thread state (e.g. suspended), memory + CPU usage, start time, priority, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949725/how-to-get-thread-state-e-g-suspended-memory-cpu-usage-start-time-priori)