# Thread wait reasons

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I've been using code that I found in the following post:

[How to get thread state (e.g. suspended), memory + CPU usage, start time, priority, etc](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/22949725/)

I'm examining thread state, and there's the following enum that describes the reasons for thread 'waiting' status -

```
enum KWAIT_REASON
{
    Executive,
    FreePage,
    PageIn,
    PoolAllocation,
    DelayExecution,
    Suspended,
    UserRequest,
    WrExecutive,
    WrFreePage,
    WrPageIn,
    WrPoolAllocation,
    WrDelayExecution,
    WrSuspended,
    WrUserRequest,
    WrEventPair,
    WrQueue,
    WrLpcReceive,
    WrLpcReply,
    WrVirtualMemory,
    WrPageOut,
    WrRendezvous,
    Spare2,
    Spare3,
    Spare4,
    Spare5,
    Spare6,
    WrKernel,
    MaximumWaitReason
};
```

Can anyone explain what `WrQueue` is, and perhaps what the difference between `WrUserRequest` and `UserRequest` is?

The information is obtained using `NtQuerySystemInformation()` with `SystemProcessInformation`.

Comment: `SystemProcessInformation` does not return any thread wait reason information.

Comment: @IInspectable In the code from that post I see that it returns array of SYSTEM_PROCESS, which holds SYSTEM_THREAD array for each one of the processes. SYSTEM_THREAD holds the wait reason

Comment: @IInspectable - you mistake. `SystemProcessInformation` return array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` which containing array of `SYSTEM_[EXTENDED_]THREAD_INFORMATION` and here exist member `KWAIT_REASON WaitReason;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WrQueue` this is when thread waits on `KQUEUE` object (look it definition in `wdm.h`) in kernel. this can be call to `ZwRemoveIoCompletion` or Win32 shell `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` (*IOCP* is exactly `KQUEUE` object). or thread (begining from vista) call `ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory` ([worker factory](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=6) internally use `KQUEUE`. also possible that thread in kernel calls [`KeRemoveQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549605(v=vs.85).aspx) - this usually does system working threads.

`WrUserRequest` is used by win32k.sys subsystem. Usually this is when thread calls `GetMessage`. So if we view `WrUserRequest` we can be sure that thread is waiting for window messages.

`UserRequest` - this means that thread waits on some object[s] via `WaitForSingleObject[Ex]` or `WaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]` (or it equivalents)